# Does Mocha ignore --harmony option in mocha.opts?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, ecmascript-harmony

In my test directory, I have a file `mocha.opts` containing the following:

```
--harmony
--recursive
--growl
--reporter spec
--require should
```

When I run `mocha`, I get the following error:

```
/project/server/utilities/encryption.js:3
const
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

This is, of course, because my use of `const` requires ES6 Harmony.  When I run `mocha --harmony`, my tests execute just fine.  And the other entries in my `mocha.opts` file work as expected.

Does the `mocha.opts` file ignore the `--harmony` argument for some reason?  Or am I doing it wrong?  The Mocha docs don't elaborate and I haven't been able to find the answer here or anywhere else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The asker asks:

> When I run `mocha --harmony`, my tests execute just fine. [...]
>
> Does the `mocha.opts` file ignore the `--harmony` argument for some reason?

Yes, `mocha.opts` ignores the `--harmony` argument. The `--harmony` option is not a Mocha option but a Node.js option. This is an option that must be passed to Node.js *before* it starts executing. However, `mocha.opts` is read after Node.js has started and so even if Mocha was able to understand the option, it would not be able to do anything about it.

But why does it work on the command line? Shouldn't it be the case that when I run `mocha --harmony`, Mocha has to first start before parsing the `--harmony` option? No, because `mocha` is script that starts the "real" Mocha. The shell script detects `--harmony` and makes sure it is passed to Node.js when it starts the "real" Mocha.

Comment: Nitpick - mocha is a js script that call the real Mocha. It is not a shell script.

Comment: mocha could use `execv()` to replace itself with "proper node". Everybody does that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not support as something you can include in `mocha.opts`. You much add in to the command line when you call `mocha`. See [this](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1109).